# Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 2.ts FirebaseX Ionic native plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I need to use Firebase Phone Auth with FirebaseX plugin. I have tried like so:

```
 async getVerificationCode(): void {

    const res:any = await this.firebaseX.verifyPhoneNumber('+16505553434', 60);

  }
```

But it says like this:

> Expected 3-4 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554) index.d.ts(347, 96): An
>   argument for 'phoneNumber' was not provided.

```
  "@ionic/angular": "5.1.1",
  "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.26.0",
  "firebase": "7.15.0",
```

Any clue how to use this properly?

API:

```
>   verifyPhoneNumber(success: (value: string | object) => void, error:
> (err: string) => void, phoneNumber: string, timeoutDuration?: number):
> Promise<any>;
>     /**
>      * Signs the user into Firebase with credentials obtained using verifyPhoneNumber().
>      * See the Android- and iOS-specific Firebase documentation for more info.
>      * @param {object} credential - a credential object returned by the success callback of an authentication method
>      * @param {function} success - callback function to call on successful sign-in using credentials
>      * @param {function} error - callback function which will be passed a {string} error message as an argument
>      */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expecting two callbacks before your arguments. Try

```js
const res:any = await this.firebaseX.verifyPhoneNumber(() => {}, () => {}, '+16505553434', 60);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the first time I'm using This Phone Auth with FirebaseX. It is different.

Comment: I haven't used it as well. I was suggesting based on the API you've provided.